# Django url patterns for two related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I have two models (School and Student) with one to many relationship.
my models.py are set as follows:

```
class School(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("basic_app:school_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
class Student(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```

and the urls.py file will have the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='school_list'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='school_detail'),
url(r'^create/$',views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(),name='school_create'),
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.SchoolUpdateView.as_view(),name='school_update'),
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.SchoolDeleteView.as_view(),name='school_delete'),
```

my question is I want to add to the urlpatterns list more urls for students:something like

```
 #url(r'^$',views.StudentListView.as_view(),name='student_list'),
# url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_detail'),
# url(r'^create/$',views.StudentCreateView.as_view(),name='student_create'),
# url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(),name='student_update'),
# url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentDeleteView.as_view(),name='student_delete')
```

I know my addition is not correct because each group of students should be related to a specific school. I am confused how to use id/pk in the url because for example student_detail.html url should contain both school id and student id.
sorry if this looks naive question.. but I am still learning and any help will be highly appreciated..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add another argument `school_pk` to the URL pattern, for example:

```
url(r'^school/(?P<school_pk>\d+)/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(),name='student_update'),
```

Then filter the queryset to only include students from that school.

```
class StudentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(StudentUpdateView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(school=self.kwargs['school_pk'])
```

The `UpdateView` will take care of fetching the student, because you're still using `pk` for the student pk.

Comment: ...thanks a lot ... just to confirm do I have to add school_id field to School class also? so I can use school_pk instead of the id that is automatically generated?? really appreciate your answer

Comment: You already have `school = models.ForeignKey(School, ...)`, which links each student to a school. Using `school_pk` in the URL pattern was just a suggestion, you can use any variable name you want, as long as it matches in the URL pattern and the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions…it helped me a lot ..but I think I am still doing sowething wrong…. now I am stuck here-->>>when I try to create a student and click submit it give me an error instead of redirecting me to student_detail page.
I get the following error instead:

Reverse for 'student_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 7}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['basic_app/school/(?P<pk>\\d+)/student/(?P<student_pk>\\d+)/$']

I pushed my work to github: https://github.com/wesimkhld/school     .I renamed  pk (of student class) to student_pk. I think the way I am doing is wrong

Comment: You now need to provide the school pk and student pk when reversing the URL.

Comment: the problem is I have two pk(in the same url)(for school and student). I choosed to rename student pk to student_pk by  :  `class StudentDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'student_details'
    model = models.Student
    template_name = 'basic_app/student_detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StudentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context`
and url will be` url(r'^school/(?P<pk>\d+)/student/(?P<student_pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_detail'),`    but it is not working

Comment: I used `school_pk` and `pk` for a reason. If you use `pk` and `student_pk` then my `get_queryset` example won't work. The `NoReverseMatch` error is a separate issue, so it would probably be better to ask a new question. You'll need to show code where the `NoReverseMatchError` is occurring (e.g the `{% url %}` tag in the template).

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'student(s)' to the urls to make them distinct. You may not need to add school_id to student urls as they are related by ForeignKey

```
url(r'^students$',views.StudentListView.as_view(),
    name='student_list'),
url(r'^student/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),
    name='student_detail'),
url(r'^student/create/$',views.StudentCreateView.as_view(),
    name='student_create'),
url(r'^student/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='student_update'),
url(r'^student/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentDeleteView.as_view(),
    name='student_delete')
```

Comment: ..thanks.. but each group of students should be related for a specific school. like for example if I open school A page I can see their students only and create/delete,update only school A students.not all students in the website...thanks again

Comment: Yeah, you can add the students list to the school detail page or modify the first url on this list to have school_pk and just list students under that school. You still don't need school_pk on the other 4 urls.

Comment: Actually, you will want school_pk on StudentCreate url if you want to add new student for a school without need to select school in form